# How to handle parentheis in Operator Precedence Parser?

Tags: compilers, c++

I wrote this c++ code for a operator precedence parser.
it works perfectly for expressions without parentheis.

Eg: `i*i+i` is accepted

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> grammar = {
    {"E", {"(E)", "E+E", "E*E", "i"}},
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, char>> precedence = {
    {"i", {{"i", '='}, {"+", '>'}, {"*", '>'}, {"(", ' '}, {")", '>'}, {"$", '>'}}},
{"+", {{"i", '<'}, {"+", '>'}, {"*", '<'}, {"(", '<'}, {")", '<'}, {"$", '>'}}},
{"*", {{"i", '<'}, {"+", '>'}, {"*", '>'}, {"(", '<'}, {")", '>'}, {"$", '>'}}},
{"(", {{"i", '<'}, {"+", '<'}, {"*", '<'}, {"(", '<'}, {")", '>'}, {"$", '>'}}},
{")", {{"i", '>'}, {"+", '>'}, {"*", '>'}, {"(", ' '}, {")", '>'}, {"$", '>'}}},
{"$", {{"i", '<'}, {"+", '<'}, {"*", '<'}, {"(", '<'}, {")", ' '}, {"$", '='}}}};

int notTerminal(std::string tok)
{
    return grammar.find(tok) != grammar.end();
}

std::string firstTerminal(std::vector<std::string> stack)
{
    for (int i = stack.size() - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (!notTerminal(stack[i]))
        {
            return stack[i];
        }
    }
    return "";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> stack;
    std::string input = "i*i+i$";
stack.push_back("$");
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        std::string token = input.substr(i, 1);
        std::string top = stack[stack.size() - 1];

        if (precedence[firstTerminal(stack)][token] == '>')
        {
            std::string expr = "";
            std::cout << "\nToken: " << token << "\n";

            while (precedence[firstTerminal(stack)][token] == '>' || precedence[firstTerminal(stack)][token] == '=')
            {

                expr = stack[stack.size() - 1] + expr;
                std::cout << "\nExpression: " + expr << "\n";
                stack.pop_back();
                std::cout << "Stack: ";
                for (auto s : stack)
                {
                    std::cout << s;
                }
                for (auto kv : grammar)
                {
                    for (auto v : kv.second)
                    {
                        if (v == expr)
                        {

                            std::cout << "\nReducing " << kv.first << "->" << expr << "\n";
                            stack.push_back(kv.first);
                            expr = "";
                            std::cout << "Changed Stack: ";
                            for (auto s : stack)
                            {
                                std::cout << s;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (stack[stack.size() - 1] == "$" && token == "$")
                {
                    std::cout << "\nParsing successful\n";
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (precedence[firstTerminal(stack)][token] == '<')
        {
            stack.push_back(token);
            std::cout << "\nUpdated Stack: ";
            for (auto s : stack)
            {
                std::cout << s;
            }
            i++;
        }
        else if (precedence[firstTerminal(stack)][token] == '=')
        {
            stack.push_back(token);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\nproblem Stack: ";
            for (auto s : stack)
            {
                std::cout << s;
            }
            std::cout << "\nParsing error!\n";
            return -1;
        }
    } while (i < input.length());

    for (auto s : stack)
    {
        std::cout << s;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

However it fails when I add parenthesis into the expression. Eg: `(i*i)+i` fails.
I tried changing the precedence of the brackets. However it doesn't seem to fix it.
What would be the best way for handling brackets?

Comment: Hi, first of I want to point out that your code is a bit overcomplicated. Its possible to write your procedure without ever comparing `== '=' ` or `== '>' `. I would recommend rewrite it like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser#Pseudocode), for readability (ofc you can transform the recursion to stack ops if you prefer that). On another note, this is not really a forum for debugging.